# Python Sklearn: Vectorize Edgelist

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have an edgelist in the format:

Product_B  Consumer_Id_1

Product_B  Consumer_Id_2

Product_A  Consumer_Id_3

I want to use this for item based filtering in scikit learn, for which I need to transform this into a sparse scipy matrix where each row or column represents a feature vector of a title with a one or zero if a consumer did or did not purchase that title.

The documentation on scipy is strangely confusing to me. How do I construct a sparse matrix without explicitly pivoting the array in numpy or pandas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: which sparse matrix do you want to use? Also which scikit learn function are you trying to use?

Comment: CSR and I want to decompose the matrix using PCA before clustering it with kmeans.